# Hibernate - OneToMany: Unable to find with id

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, jpa

I have webservice which saves an order in a mysql datbase with Hibernate:

this is my json Input:

```
 {
  "consignments": [
    {
      "entries": [
        {
          "entryNumber": 0,
          "productId": "0563 5231",
          "quantity": 1,
          "totalPrice": 125.00,
          "unit": "pieces"
        },
        {
          "entryNumber": 1,
          "productId": "0563 4800",
          "quantity": 1,
          "totalPrice": 125.00,
          "unit": "pieces"
        }
      ],
      "price": 125.00
    }
  ],
  "currency": "EUR",
  "erpCustomerId": "0001709147",
  "erpUnitId": "string",
  "hybrisOrderId": "1512986259483",
  "orderDate": "2017-12-08T15:52:25.560Z",
  "paymentType": "string",
  "price": {
    "deliveryCosts": 1,
    "totalCosts": 125.00
  },
  "shopId": "DE-Site",
  "shopID": "DE-Site"
}
```

This is the order object in java:

```
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    @Column(name = "hybris_order_id")
    private String hybrisOrderId;

    @Column(name = "erp_unit_id")
    private String erpUnitId;

    @Column(name = "erp_customer_id")
    private String erpCustomerId;

    @Column(name = "shop_id")
    private String shopId;

    @Column(name = "payment_type")
    private String paymentType;

    @Column(name = "currency")
    private String currency;

    @Column(name = "order_date")
    private ZonedDateTime orderDate;


    @OneToOne(cascade = {CascadeType.ALL})
    @JoinColumn(unique = true)
    private Price price;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "placedOrder", cascade = {CascadeType.ALL}, fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @Cache(usage = CacheConcurrencyStrategy.NONSTRICT_READ_WRITE)
    private Set<Consignment> consignments = new HashSet<>();

    @Column(name = "erp_order_id")
    private String erpOrderId;

    @Column(name = "erp_accepted_date")
    private ZonedDateTime erpAcceptedDate;
```

This is the consignment java object:

```
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    @Column(name = "hybris_consignment_id")
    private String hybrisConsignmentId;

    @Column(name = "price")
    private Double price;

    @JsonIgnore
    @ManyToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinColumn(name="id",referencedColumnName="id", insertable=false, updatable=false)
    private PlacedOrder placedOrder;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "consignment", cascade = {CascadeType.ALL}, fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @Cache(usage = CacheConcurrencyStrategy.NONSTRICT_READ_WRITE)
    private Set<Entry> entries = new HashSet<>();
```

This is the entry java object:

```
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    @Column(name = "entry_number")
    private Integer entryNumber;

    @Column(name = "quantity")
    private Integer quantity;

    @Column(name = "product_id")
    private String productId;

    @Column(name = "unit")
    private String unit;

    @Column(name = "total_price")
    private Double totalPrice;

    @JsonIgnore
    @ManyToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinColumn(name="id",referencedColumnName="id", insertable=false, updatable=false)
    private Consignment consignment;
```

My Problem is that when I try to get this order I added from the API, it works fine. But it misses one of the entries in the consignment list. When I try to access the entry table, i get this Exception:

```
    Resolved exception caused by Handler execution: org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaObjectRetrievalFailureException: 
Unable to find com.testo.es.cloud.os.domain.Consignment with id 2;
```

Does anyone have an idea, why the second entry is referenced to a consignment, which doesn't exist?

Best regards